# getting Unicode decode error while using gTTS in python

Tags: text-to-speech, python-2.x, translate

While using gTTS google translator module in python 2.x, I am getting error-

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtts/tts.py",
>   line 94, in **init**
>       if self._len(text) <= self.MAX_CHARS:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtts/tts.py",
>   line 154, in _len
>       return len(unicode(text)) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Even though I have included `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in my python script, I am getting the error on using Non-ASCII characters. Tell me some other way to implement like I can write sentence in English and get translated in other language. But this is also not working as I am getting speech in English, only accent changed.

I have searched a lot everywhere but can't find an answer. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried writing a string in unicode format as-
`u'Qu'est-ce que tu fais? Gardez-le de côté.'`.

The ASCII code characters are converted into unicode format and hence, resolve the error. So, the text you want to be converted into speech can even have utf-8 format characters and can be easily transformed.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to decode the incoming argument in the gtts-cli.py

Change the following line from this:

```
if args.text == "-":
    text = sys.stdin.read()
else:
    text = arg.text
```

to this:

```
if args.text == "-":
    text = sys.stdin.read()
else:
    text = codecs.decode(arg.text,"utf-8")
```

works for me, give it a try.